# Large mySQL Geometry Intersection Searches

Tags: php, mysql, gis

I presently have a large number of routes on my Google Maps that are generated using KML files that can be overlaid etc.  A possible way of untangling the routes is to use a selection box drawing on the map and using its coordinates select the list of routes and allow the user via a drop down to select a certain route.

In mySQL an example method of achieving this is to define a polygon using the `LINESTRING` geometry and then looking for the routes that intersect this rectangle. In the application these are inserted into the PHP query string etc.

```
SET @g1 = ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0)');
SET @g2 = ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (-4 5,5 5,10 5,12 5)');
SELECT ST_INTERSECTS(@g1,@g2)
```

Now the question I have is because this SQL statment `SELECT ST_INTERSECTS(@g1,@g2)` returns a simple `true of false` I will need to loop through every single route to form a collection of routes that test positive.   This will work, but where there are a lot of routes this is going to impose a very heavy load on the application - is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have lots of geometries stored within database? If that's true, you will have to write a more complex query that st_intersects. Look here and see if it helps you http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/179521/61844

Comment: Yes it does.  Thank you very much.  To answer your question, I only have a single column to check.